# pdo execute give's error

Tags: mysql, pdo

Yesterday i had this topic with "pdo inserting and updating. Now here is the following

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in  on line 148
```

And this is my code.

```
$sth = $db->prepare(


'INSERT INTO track (`rsname`, `overallranknow`, `overalllevelnow`, `overallxpnow` )' .
  'VALUES (:name, :Overalln, :Overall1, :Overall2) '. 
  'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' .
    "rsname = :name"  .
    "overallranknow = :Overalln" .
    "overalllevelnow = :Overall1" .
    "overallxpnow = :Overall2" 
);
$sth->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':Overalln', $Overalln, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall1', $Overall[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall2', $Overall[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

The error says my execute line is the wrong 1. I have tried it with a array and i still got it then. I hope maybe knows what i mean.

~Kev (bad english = sorry)

Comment: You're trying to insert into 5 fields (rsname, overallranknow, overalllevelnow and overallxpnow), yet you only supply 4 values (:name, :Overalln, :Overall1, :Overall2) - you need to supply as many values as the number of fields you set. Either (a) remove a field name or (b) add a variable to hold the value for that field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO track (rsname, overallranknow, overalllevelnow, overallxpnow)
       VALUES (:name, :Overalln, :Overall1, :Overall2)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
       rsname = values(rsname), 
       overallranknow = values(overallranknow),
       overalllevelnow = values(overalllevelnow),
       overallxpnow = values(overallxpnow)
```

it have to be.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PDO::prepare manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php);

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). **You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement.**

That (sadly) means that you'll have to duplicate your bindings with secondary names to use the same value twice in a query. Not pretty, something like;

```
$sth = $db->prepare(
  'INSERT INTO track (`rsname`, `overallranknow`, `overalllevelnow`, `overallxpnow` )' .
    'VALUES (:name, :Overalln, :Overall1, :Overall2) '. 
    'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' .
      "rsname = :name_2"  .
      "overallranknow = :Overalln_2" .
      "overalllevelnow = :Overall1_2" .
      "overallxpnow = :Overall2_2" 
);
$sth->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':name_2', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':Overalln', $Overalln, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':Overalln_2', $Overalln, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall1', $Overall[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall1_2', $Overall[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall2', $Overall[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall2_2', $Overall[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

EDIT: Since MySQL allows for the [`VALUES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) keyword in `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to not have to repeat the parameters, you'd be better off using @YourCommonSense's answer for this exact case.

Comment: @Kev30 Did you change the names in both the bindings and the SQL in the prepare? A quick test does not give me that error anymore.

Comment: They are already correct when u gived the code, i did not have to change something.